# How to append check box inside a table of Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
//assume I have the response data as follows:
var response[] = { blake,blake@gmail.com,fofehu45555,ontario,toronto }, {flake,flake@gmail.com,kokehu45555,ontario,toronto}; 

for(i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){

$("#table").append('<input type="checkbox"'"<tr class='tr'> <td> "+response.data[i].user_name+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].userr_contact+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].user_license+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].userr_email+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].state+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].city);}
```

```html
<button onclick="myfunction();">Go</button>
<table id="table" border=1>
  <tr>
   <th> Name </th>
   <th> contact </th>
   <th> license </th>
   <th> email </th>
   <th> state </th>
   <th> city </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to append this checkbox inside the table accurately, so that I can give the permission to the client to select few of the response data and give a new request again by the click of a button (onclick).

The tricky part that im struggling with this is i want to get the email address of the selected checkboxes stored in a variable/ array variable

Comment: Your objects are missing property keys. Also, the way you declared the `response` variable is invalid and it is going to throw a syntax error.

Comment: Why you don't append the checkbox when you generate the response, it can be a solution and assign to the checkbox the id (unique) of each response. Of course if you can manipulate the response from server side and doing in this way will be much simple for you to create an event when click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your response is in this format:

```
var response = [
  { 
    user_name: 'blake',
    user_email: 'blake@gmail.com',
    user_licence: 'fofehu45555',
    user_state: 'ontario',
    user_city: 'toronto' 
  },
  { 
    user_name: 'flake',
    user_email: 'flake@gmail.com',
    user_licence: 'kokehu45555',
    user_state: 'ontario',
    user_city: 'toronto' 
  }
];
```

one more readable way to create what you want is:

```
response.forEach(function(user) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>');
    var nameTd = $('<td/>', {text: user.user_name});
    var checkbox = $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', value: user.user_email }).prependTo(nameTd);
    nameTd.appendTo(tr);
    var contactTd = $('<td/>', {text: user.user_contact}).appendTo(tr);
    var licenceTd = $('<td/>', {text: user.user_licence}).appendTo(tr);
    var emailTd = $('<td/>', {text: user.user_email}).appendTo(tr);
    var stateTd = $('<td/>', {text: user.user_state}).appendTo(tr);
    var cityTd = $('<td/>', {text: user.user_city}).appendTo(tr);
    $('table tbody').append(tr);
});
```

You html should look something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
           <th> Name </th>
           <th> contact </th>
           <th> license </th>
           <th> email </th>
           <th> state </th>
           <th> city </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jo5fmrhy/14/)

Then you can get the checked users' emails like this:

```
var selected = $('input:checkbox:checked');
var emails = [];
selected.each(function(){
    emails.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Assume I have the response data as follows

Hew... No. Because I feel that this is your issue.
Else, the answer is: Get the server script that is producing such a malformed "response" and fix it.

So I reworked a lot in there, to show you a working example.

As mentionned in comments, the `response` declaration, which is the starting point, is invalid. I structured it in a "commonly seen" way... Which is an object containint an array of objects.

Objects have propety names... Which you were tring to refer to in the jQuery append. So I added them.

Then, in the append, you placed the checkbox outside the `tr`... That's not good. I placed it in the name cell... But I would prefer to add a table colunm for it. You to decide.

You also had some quotes issue on that string to append.

```js
$("#goBtn").on("click",function(){

  //assume I have the response data as follows:
  var response = {
    data:[
        {
          user_name: "blake",
          user_email: "blake@gmail.com",
          user_contact: "fofehu45555",
          state: "ontario",
          city: "toronto",
          user_license: ""
        },
        {
          user_name: "flake",
          user_email: "flake@gmail.com",
          user_contact: "kokehu45555",
          state: "ontario",
          city: "toronto",
          user_license: ""
        }
      ]
  };

  for(i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){

    $("#table").append("<tr class='tr'> <td> <input type='checkbox'> "+response.data[i].user_name+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].user_contact+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].user_license+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].user_email+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].state+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].city);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="goBtn">Go</button>
<table id="table" border=1>
  <tr>
   <th> Name </th>
   <th> contact </th>
   <th> license </th>
   <th> email </th>
   <th> state </th>
   <th> city </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove double quotes for type="checkbox"

it caused the error syntax uncaught error for me.

try instead type=checkbox